# Mobile before element display issue

Tags: html, css, webkit, mobile-webkit

What it looks like in a normal browser...

[image]

What it looks like on mobile...

[image]

```css
main > header > div {
  width: 100%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: -71.71%;
  text-align: center;
}

main > header > div div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

main > header > div div::before {
  content: "";
  height: 9.8vw;
  min-height: 3.55rem;
  width: 950px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -950px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

main > header h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 210%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <div>
      <img src="./images/ks.svg">
      <div>
        <h1>WELCOME TO</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>KYLE SULLIVAN'S</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Design | Develop | Deploy</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

If you have any ideas what's causing this behaviour, please help.

As you can see I'm trying to have the text background appear to continue far off the left side.

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  When asking for help on issues like this, it's best to provide the HTML/CSS/etc that you are using, so that folks here can take a look and provide some suggestions/guidance directly.

Comment: @Turnip completely forgot, added it now.

Comment: You  have a fixed width on your ::before content, so it isn't going to be responsive.  Try using a % for the width, or media queries to change the width on smaller screens.

Comment: @Maulzal I've tested using % for the width and it's not the issue. I'm assuming there is some strange mobile display issue going on maybe a wekbit problem but I'm not sure.